# WPF - how to concatenate textblocks?

Tags: xaml

I'm developing a scientific application and need to render a string like this:-

**Result: 350cps/ppb**

The numeric part (350) and the measurement unit ("ppb") are both bound properties, while "Result" and "cps" are localized strings. (Also note that the "Result" resource string doesn't include the ":", so I can re-use the word in other places).

I'm using the following XAML to output such a string:-

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static ar:AppResources.Result}" />
    :
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Measurement}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static ar:AppResources.Counts_per_second_abbrev}" />
    /
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UnitOfMeasure.Name}" />
</TextBlock>
```

But the problem with this approach is that a space is inserted between each element because they are on separate lines, resulting in something like this:

**Result : 350 cps / ppb**

To get it formatted correctly I can use the following, but it's not very readable (and the ":" and "/" are easy to miss):-

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static ar:AppResources.Result}" />:
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Measurement}" /><TextBlock Text="{x:Static ar:AppResources.Counts_per_second_abbrev}" />/<TextBlock Text="{Binding UnitOfMeasure.Name}" />
</TextBlock>
```

I guess I could use a couple of horizontal StackPanels instead, but is there a "proper" way to concatenate text without the whitespace being added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I found this (I hadn't twigged that I could use statics in a MultiBinding):-

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}: {1}{2}/{3}">
            <Binding Source="{x:Static ar:AppResources.Result}" />
            <Binding Path="Measurement" />
            <Binding Source="{x:Static ar:AppResources.Counts_per_second_abbrev}" />
            <Binding Path="UnitOfMeasure.Name" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```